# Act on a path passed as argument in a shell script

Tags: unix

I'm trying to print a list of the directories within a directory path i'm passing to a bash script.
I know that

```
    ls -dn */
```

will print the list of only dirs within the current path, 
but i want to print the ones within the path i provided to the script.

Comment: i am guessing that you want to print only the path of the dir which you provide with your script .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ls` with the variable also to list directories:

```
p="somepath"
ls -dn "$p"/*/
```

Or using find:

```
find "$p" -type d -maxdepth 1
```

Comment: -maxdepth 1 is not necessary

Comment: I added `-maxdepth 1` to make sure to get directories from 1st level only, otherwise it will find directories from any level below given path.

Comment: mmm that useful, thank. by the way, i noticed that -maxdepth 1 should appear after "$p" and before -type..